how to inherit the BarcodeModel in odoo 16
hi every one in odoo 16 I working on module to update the BarcodeModel in stock_barcode addon so I found this JavaScript file in odoo stock_barcode addon and I want to make extention from this class
/** @odoo-module **/

import BarcodeParser from 'barcodes.BarcodeParser';
import { ConfirmationDialog } from "@web/core/confirmation_dialog/confirmation_dialog";
import { Mutex } from "@web/core/utils/concurrency";
import LazyBarcodeCache from '@stock_barcode/lazy_barcode_cache';
import { _t } from 'web.core';
import { sprintf } from '@web/core/utils/strings';
import { useService } from "@web/core/utils/hooks";

const { EventBus } = owl;

export default class BarcodeModel extends EventBus {
    constructor(params, services) {
        super();
    }
       
    //code here 

    async _processBarcode(barcode) {
        //code here 
    }
}

I want to make extention from this class in my module and make overwide the method _processBarcode to make changes on it
can any one help me.
